# Sample Pyspark DataFrame by date with number of days from last entry between each sample

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, sampling

Given a DataFrame:

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import Row

dataframe_rows = {
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 18)),
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 21)),
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 22)),
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30)),
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 18)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 22)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 28)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 13)),
}

df_example = spark.createDataFrame(dataframe_rows).orderBy(["id", "date"], ascending=[1, 1])
```

So

```
df_example.show()
```

yields

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|               date|
+---+-------------------+
|  A|2015-01-18 00:00:00|
|  A|2015-02-21 00:00:00|
|  A|2015-02-22 00:00:00|
|  A|2015-06-30 00:00:00|
|  A|2017-12-31 00:00:00|
|  B|2019-01-18 00:00:00|
|  B|2019-01-21 00:00:00|
|  B|2019-02-22 00:00:00|
|  B|2019-02-28 00:00:00|
|  B|2019-12-13 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

I want a function that will sample rows from this DataFrame such that a specified number of days are between each sample and such that the last date per id is the last date per id in the sampled DataFrame.

For example, using 14 days between each sample,

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|               date|
+---+-------------------+
|  A|2015-01-18 00:00:00|
|  A|2015-02-22 00:00:00|
|  A|2015-06-30 00:00:00|
|  A|2017-12-31 00:00:00|
|  B|2019-01-18 00:00:00|
|  B|2019-02-28 00:00:00|
|  B|2019-12-13 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

Note the last date for each id is the same as it was in the original DataFrame.

Edit:  The solution below works with the original DataFrame that I provided but if I change it

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

dataframe_rows = {
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2000, 11, 12)),
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 13)),
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 29)),
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 30)),
    Row(id = "A", date = datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 31)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 18)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 21)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 27)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 28)),
    Row(id = "B", date = datetime.datetime(2002, 12, 13)),
}

df_example = spark.createDataFrame(dataframe_rows).orderBy(["id", "date"], ascending=[1, 1])
df_example.show()
```

yielding

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|               date|
+---+-------------------+
|  A|2000-11-12 00:00:00|
|  A|2000-12-13 00:00:00|
|  A|2000-12-29 00:00:00|
|  A|2000-12-30 00:00:00|
|  A|2000-12-31 00:00:00|
|  B|2002-02-18 00:00:00|
|  B|2002-02-21 00:00:00|
|  B|2002-02-27 00:00:00|
|  B|2002-02-28 00:00:00|
|  B|2002-12-13 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

and apply the code I get

```
+---+----------+
| id|      date|
+---+----------+
|  A|2000-11-12|
|  A|2000-12-13|
|  A|2000-12-31|
|  B|2002-02-27|
|  B|2002-02-28|
|  B|2002-12-13|
+---+----------+
```

I am not sure why both February dates survive.  I expected to see

```
+---+----------+
| id|      date|
+---+----------+
|  A|2000-11-12|
|  A|2000-12-13|
|  A|2000-12-31|
|  B|2002-02-28|
|  B|2002-12-13|
+---+----------+
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct timestamp resampling function in pyspark. However, I found a helper function from [this blogpost](https://mihevc.org/2016/09/28/spark-resampling.html) which solves this issue. The function converts the timestamp to unix timestamp and aggregates the data based on your specified resampling interval.

> unix timestamp is a representation of timestamp in seconds starting from 1 January 1970. For example, 1 January 1970 00:00:00 = 0 seconds, 1 January 1970 01:00:00 = 3600 seconds, 2 January 1970 00:00:00 = 86400 seconds

After making a resampled column using that function, you can continue by doing a `.groupBy()` and aggration using `F.last()` from pyspark.

#### Resampling Function

Edit (May 19th, 2021): Added offset

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def resample(column, agg_interval=900, offset=0, time_format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):
    if type(column)==str:
        column = F.col(column)

    # Convert the timestamp to unix timestamp format.
    # Unix timestamp = number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC, 1 January 1970.
    col_ut =  F.unix_timestamp(column, format=time_format)

    # Divide the time into dicrete intervals, by rounding. 
    col_ut_agg =  F.floor( (col_ut + offset) / agg_interval) * agg_interval 

    # Convert to and return a human readable timestamp
    return F.from_unixtime(col_ut_agg)
```

#### Resampling without offset

```
# 14 days = 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 14 days
df_example\
    .withColumn('date_resampled', resample(df_example.date, 60*60*24*14))\
    .groupBy('date_resampled')\
    .agg(F.last('id').alias('id'), F.last('date').alias('date'))\
    .orderBy(['id', 'date'])\
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+---+-------------------+
|     date_resampled| id|               date|
+-------------------+---+-------------------+
|2000-11-09 00:00:00|  A|2000-11-12 00:00:00|
|2000-12-07 00:00:00|  A|2000-12-13 00:00:00|
|2000-12-21 00:00:00|  A|2000-12-31 00:00:00|
|2002-02-14 00:00:00|  B|2002-02-27 00:00:00|
|2002-02-28 00:00:00|  B|2002-02-28 00:00:00|
|2002-12-05 00:00:00|  B|2002-12-13 00:00:00|
+-------------------+---+-------------------+
```

#### Resampling with offset

If conducted without offset, resampling will start from 1 January 1970 00:00:00 GMT. With 1 day offset, resampling will start from 2 January 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

```
# 14 days = 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 14 days
# offset = 10 days
df_example\
    .withColumn('date_resampled', resample(df_example.date, 60*60*24*14, 60*60*24*10))\
    .groupBy('date_resampled')\
    .agg(F.last('id').alias('id'), F.last('date').alias('date'))\
    .orderBy(['id', 'date'])\
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+---+-------------------+
|     date_resampled| id|               date|
+-------------------+---+-------------------+
|2000-11-09 00:00:00|  A|2000-11-12 00:00:00|
|2000-12-21 00:00:00|  A|2000-12-13 00:00:00|
|2001-01-04 00:00:00|  A|2000-12-31 00:00:00|
|2002-02-28 00:00:00|  B|2002-02-28 00:00:00|
|2002-12-19 00:00:00|  B|2002-12-13 00:00:00|
+-------------------+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: I edited my original post.  I am running into an issue with the code you provided on a different dataset.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: That's because the resampling starts from `1 January 1970` and if you add 14 days over and over on the date, it will eventually start at `14 February 2002`. When you another 14 days it will start at `28 February 2002`. Thus, 27 February 2002 and 28 February 2002 is added to the data because they're the last dates respectively for 14 February 2002 and 28 February 2002. If you want them to not be resampled, you can add an offset (Explained in the updated answer).

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!